# how to know the Notebook path of the databricks file in execute pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I create a template of Databricks job on my ADF and I want to use that template again n again.
but i am not able to understand from where i can get the Notebook_path

[image]

the notebook template is
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide notebook_template pipeline image?

Comment: which activities you are using in invoked pipeline?

Comment: You can select the path at databricks notebook activity itself why yo are creating new parameter as notebook path, it will take the notebook path from notebook activity.

Comment: If you want to use it in template, then you can make use of the pipeline json.

Answer (score 0):

To get notebook path you can follow below procedure:
Create new notebook to get list of notebooks in databricks with below code:

```
import requests
import json

my_json = {"path": "/Users/v-xxxx@xxxx.com/"} 
auth = {"Authorization": "Bearer <access token>"}
response = requests.get('<databricksworkspace>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/list', json = my_json, headers=auth).json()
dbutils.notebook.exit(response)
```

[image]

Run above notebook with databricks notebook activity in ADF. Add filter activity to the notebook activity to remove above notebook from the list.  Add below expression in item

```
@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput.objects
```

Create parameter list add above notebook name as value and add below expression in condition:

```
@not(equals(last(split(string(item().path),'/')), pipeline().parameters.list))
```

[image]

add foreach activity to the filter activity and add below expression to the item:

```
@activity('Filter1').output.value
```

Add execution pipeline activity and invoke the required pipeline and retrieve path name with `@item().path` then you will able to get the path.

[image]

[image]